# Troubles with <termios.h> in a C++ app

Tags: c++, debian, termios

I'm trying to interface a C++ program and a serial port and I have a problem receiving data using "termios.h". I'm on Debian, using Eclipse and G++. Everything is ok, except I only receive part of the message (I think).

My port is connected to a Wavecom Modem and I receive SMS transactions I need to analyse. Port, rate and every stuff are ok.

If I connect an external analyzer (CuteCom), the message received is correct for every sms : +CMTI: "SMS", xx
(xx is a sequential number)

If I use another library (C, not C++) "RS232.h", it's also ok : +CMTI: "SMS",xx

If I use "termios.h" I only receive : +CMTI:

no "SMS" and no number. It looks like termios doesn't like the « " » and thinks it's the end of the string.

I unfortunately need to use C++ for the project. Does anyone of you has encounter this trouble before ? Is there someone who would be able to give me some hints to check the termios librairy ?

Thanks.

FZ

Comment: Try to read this doc, if you haven't already. Maybe it can help you: https://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html

Comment: Already have checked the doc.. but was not able to see something helping me.

Comment: Long time ago I had to implement a communication via UART to test an embedded software. I used termios.h and I remember that I had problems with receiving just parts of message. Take care at baudrates, line control functions and so on. Don't remember how I solved the problem. I remember a site that helped me, https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Serial_Programming/termios. Sorry I can't help you more!